# How to add legend in a 3D scatterplot

Tags: r, 3d

I have a 3D scatter plot that looks like this

[image: 3D scatter plot]

and the code associated with it is as follows

```
nr = c(114,114,1820,100,100)
acc = c(70.00,45.00,98.89,82.00,74.90)
ti = c(25.00,87.50,0.25,41.40,51.30)
label = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
data = data.frame(nr, acc, ti, label)
library(scatterplot3d)
scatterplot3d(data$nr, data$acc, data$ti, main = "3D Plot - Requirements, Accuracy & Time", xlab = "Number of requirements", ylab = "Accuracy", zlab = "Time", pch = data$label, angle = 45)
```

Now, I want to add a legend to the bottom right to indicate what those symbols mean

```
tech <- c('BPL','W','RT','S','WSM')
```

For instance, the triangle stands for BPL, + for RT and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
# define a plot
s3d <-scatterplot3d(data$nr, data$acc, data$ti, main = "3D Plot - Requirements, Accuracy & Time",
              xlab = "Number of requirements", ylab = "Accuracy", zlab = "Time", pch = data$label, angle = 45)

# add a legend
legend("topright",s3d$xyz.convert(18, 0, 12), pch = data$label, yjust=0,
       # here you define the labels in the legend
       legend = c('BPL','W','RT','S','WSM'), cex = 1.1
       )
```

[image]